# How does Onionshare work?

Tags: onion-services, onion-routing

How exactly does [OnionShare](https://onionshare.org/) work to allow one to send files using onion domains?

Answer (score 1):

OnionShare allows you to *share* files over onions, it will allow you to offer them to other users for download.

It packages a lightweight, native python httpd called [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). When you start OnionShare, you provide it a list of files you want to share, it loads the files into a single zip file and uses a simple page template with a link to the zip file and then starts the httpd on some high numbered port to serve the page and zip file to the visitor(s).

It uses the [stem](https://stem.torproject.org) library to connect to a running Tor's control port, trying each of the common ports in turn if it is not explicitly defined in the users environment. It then uses the `ADD_ONION` method to create an ephemeral hidden service if the Tor version is >=2.7.1 (when the functionality was added) otherwise it create a temporary directory and configures it as the place to store the information associated with the onion service.

Once it has successfully published the newly generated onion service it performs a self-connectivity test to ensure that it is able to reach the onion over Tor and if it's successful it will provide you with a link to give other users, from which they can download the zipped up set of files you wanted to share.

Answer (score 0):

It makes a locally-hosted instance of a webserver, basically, that self-destructs on successfull download of the file that is being shared.